# Jquery change function doesn't update variable correctly in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, jquery-select2, onchange

i'm using jquery change function but when i change input value i got an empty string !! this is my code any help plz :

```js
class SearchForm extends React.Component{
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {input_term_value: "",spaces_list: ""};
   }
   componentDidMount() {
    var space_change_value = "";
    $("input.sp-autocomplete-spaces").change(function() {
     space_change_value = $(this).val();
    });
    this.setState({spaces_list: space_change_value});
   }
   updateInputValue(evt){
    this.setState({input_term_value: evt.target.value});
   }
   componentDidUpdate (prevProps, prevState) {
       this.sendGetRequest();
   }
   sendGetRequest(){
    var _this = this;
    this.serverRequest = 
    axios
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should nest all your code in the `change` handler, use a fat arrow change handler to preserve your `this` scope and instead of pulling your value from `$(this).val()`, you should be accepting an event param and use `e.target.value` to get the input value:

```
$("input.sp-autocomplete-spaces").change( e => {
    this.setState({ spaces_list: e.target.value });
});
```

Comment: TypeError: this.setState is not a function !!

Comment: It's because you didn't bind your `change` handler to your component. One sec, I'll update my answer.

Comment: i got this error TypeError: elem.nodeName is undefined

Comment: Couple options: change `$(this).val()` to `$("input.sp-autocomplete-spaces").val()` or change your function to: `.change( e => this.setState({ spaces_list: e.target.value }) );`

Answer (score 0):

As I can't see any markup, I'll assume there's no ref used to select the element once mounted to the `DOM`, what you have to do :

- Use a `DOM` ref instead of `CSS` selector.
- Set the state inside the callback.

Don't forget you can use `onChange` directly in your input element as well.